# How to recycle Bitmaps in gridview adapter?

Tags: android

I have a Grid View in my android app.I am loading images to the Grid view from server.I am using lazy loading. I have to recycle all bitmaps created here.How to do Bitmap.recycle() in Adapter or Grid view. I am getting out of memory, please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to show some code (your adapter at a minimum). If you're getting out of memory errors, you probably are not implementing view recycling correctly, or otherwise have a memory leak. Its also possible that you're simply loading too many large bitmaps at once, but if you can load the view at all, its much more likely you have a memory leak.

No one is going to be able to track down a memory leak without looking at some code. Bitmap.recycle() is not a solution, the garbage collector will work well enough without it if the rest of your code is ok.

See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk for a great talk on managing memory in android and finding memory leaks.

Also try: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html for an example of how to download or otherwise correctly asynchronously load images into a list like view.

Edit: also check out an image loading library I wrote, so you don't need to worry about any of this: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) Android Training class. It has a lesson, [Displaying Bitmaps in your UI](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#gridview), that covers displaying bitmaps in a GridView using a background thread and a memory and disk cache.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really simple way that works very well:

First, you must create a custom ImageView like this:

```
public class ImageViewRecyclable extends ImageView
{
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public ImageViewRecyclable(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
    {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        if (bitmap != null) bitmap.recycle();
        this.bitmap = bm;
    }
}
```

Our ImageViewRecyclable keep a pointer to the bitmap and recycle the old one before setting the new one.

Second, you must check in the getView of the adapter to see if convertView is null or not. if it's not null cast to our custom ImageViewRecyclable and set the bitmap on it. this way the old bitmap is recycled before setting the new one.

This is the getView code of the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageViewRecyclable imageView = (convertView == null) ? new ImageViewRecyclable(ActivityMain.this) : (ImageViewRecyclable) convertView;
    byte[] bytes = ....
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return imageView;
}
```

I tested this code with 1000 100x100 images. The original ImageView failed after showing 50 image with memory error but this code works very well until the end of the grid.

This code works very great for small offline images, but online and large images need caching and other things. This may be useful but some changes must be applied.