# Grow heap (frag case) on GridView Android

Tags: android, bitmap

So I'm having a GridView and each item has a TextView and an ImageView. ImageView's drawables are being parsed by the res/drawable folder. When I'm on my getView() method ( on my custom Adapter ) I was just adding each drawable based on the position. 
So the code was pretty much like :

```
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

which gave me a few Grow Heap (frag case) like :

```
Grow heap (frag case) to 13.800MB for 1166416-byte allocation
Grow heap (frag case) to 15.834MB for 1128016-byte allocation
Grow heap (frag case) to 17.829MB for 453616-byte allocation
```

I'm using 12 images ( jpeg files ) with total size 1.6M

So I changed my code based on [load bitmap](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) article on d.android.com. 
With *calculateInSampleSize* I'm getting a factor of 1,2 or 4 based on the size of the jpeg.
Setting those values to options.inSampleSize I thought it was enough to reduce my heap size but I'm getting the same Grow Heap messages on my logcat!

Tried also the *inPurgeable* option but didn't help either.

What I still get is :

```
Grow heap (frag case) to 13.958MB for 1166416-byte allocation
Grow heap (frag case) to 15.834MB for 1128016-byte allocation
```

Any advice on this?What am I doing wrong? Why the `options.inSampleSize` doesn't help me reduce the byte allocation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to recycle your bitmap images..

this might help you

[How to recycle Bitmaps in gridview adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074694/how-to-recycle-bitmaps-in-gridview-adapter)